# My build mode is Release but as a output I get Debug folder, what is the problem?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I need to build Release version of the project. In order to get Release version I switch at the top my build mode from Debug to Release, click Build and I get an output in Debug folder like `...\bin\x64\Debug` and actually if I build in Debug I also get an output at the same location.

What I expect is if I build in Debug I get output at this location `...\bin\x64\Debug` when I build a release I get an output at this location ``...\bin\x64\Release`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cap here: you've set output folder of release build to the same location as debug build.

Comment: @user7860670 I am a new with Visual Studio, how to change it?

Comment: @user7860670 actually I checked, it is not... In build I have `Debug` for debug and `Release` for release...

Comment: same location is no issue. it will create Debug folder and Release folder respectively.  actually if you change debug mode to release, it supposes to be ok. how about clean .vs folder and rebuild again?

Comment: If you insist that it is not just a mere typo in project settings that you should provide [mcve], or at least show the project settings you are using and build log.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my issue was here at the top you can see CPU configuration (x64, AnyCPU...), if you open this configuration you can see such pop up

[image]

In front of each project configuration you can see `Debug`. So in debug it should be `Debug` and if you switch it to release it should be `Release`, but for me it was still Debug... I don't know why. I changed this to Release and all is fine now